# How to send response to the client before executing the calculations that are not required in response

Tags: http, go, response, goroutine

Can we send response(or write on user side)with statement like:

```
json.NewEncoder(w).Encode("some data")
```

in api before doing some calculation part which are not required in response but needed to store in database. I am thinking like we can give response in less time to the user and other part of function will be continue to work until the return statement.

Correct me if I am thinking in wrong direction.

Comment: Once the response is written you can't change it. One thing you can do is use the data before sending the response and then change it afterwards

Comment: thanx himanshu. More specifically when the json.NewEncoder().Encode line will execute in function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way would be to do your additional work which is not required for the response in another goroutine:

```
func someHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    go func() {
        // Do anything here, this won't delay the response
        // But don't touch the writer or request, as they may not be available here
    }()

    if err := json.NewEncoder(w).Encode("some data"); err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error sending response: %v", err)
    }
}
```

Note that in the launched gorotuine you can't use the `http.ResponseWriter` nor the `http.Request`, as they are only valid to use until you return from your handler. If you need something from them, you must make a copy of the needed parts before you launch the goroutine.

If you want to complete the additional task before you return from the handler, you can still use a goroutine, and use a `sync.WaitGroup` to wait for it to complete and only then return from the handler. You may or may not flush the response:

```
func someHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()

        // You may use the writer and request here
    }()

    if err := json.NewEncoder(w).Encode("some data"); err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error sending response: %v", err)
    }

    // Optionally you may flush the data written so far (icnluding HTTP headers)
    if flusher, ok := w.(http.Flusher); ok {
        flusher.Flush()
    }

    wg.Wait()
}
```

Note that here the goroutine is allowed to use the `http.ResponseWriter` and `http.Request`, because the handler does not return until the additional task is completed.

Comment: thanx @icza. But more specifically i want to that can we write response on "w" of json.NewEncode(w) before or in middle of  execution of the function so that complete code after that line should also be excuted but response should have been already written on "w". (let me clear this that code after that point is not related to response)

Comment: @RohitGhule Yes, and my suggested solution allows you to do just that.

Comment: Thank you @icza. It works exactly as per my requirement.